# Picking random element from an array in Ruby ONCE ONLY

Tags: ruby, arrays, random, sample, shuffle

I know I can pick a random element out of an array with the sample method but this leaves the possibility of an element being picked more than once. I could shuffle the array first and then go from first to last element in order but I understand this is memory intensive and I am looking for a less intensive method if possible!

Comment: Why do you say that shuffling an array is memory intensive? Most naive implementations shuffle the array in place.

Comment: Docs state that `#sample` will not select elements more than once. `[1, 2].sample(3)` returns `[1, 2]` or `[2, 1]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shuffling an array is not memory intensive. Ruby has a default in place shuffle implementation, it's called [`Array.shuffle!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-shuffle-21). Looking at the source code for this you can see (it's C):

```
rb_ary_shuffle_bang(ary)
    VALUE ary;
{
    long i = RARRAY(ary)->len;

    rb_ary_modify(ary);
    while (i) {
        long j = rb_genrand_real()*i;
        VALUE tmp = RARRAY(ary)->ptr[--i];
        RARRAY(ary)->ptr[i] = RARRAY(ary)->ptr[j];
        RARRAY(ary)->ptr[j] = tmp;
    }
    return ary;
}
```

This implementation follows the classic [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

So:

1. Shuffle the array in place using `shuffle!`. Time complexity is `O(n)`, no extra memory needed.
2. Iterate over the array. Time complexity is `O(n)`, no extra memory needed (only an integer to hold the current index).

Overall you have what you need with no extra memory and time complexity `O(n)`.

Answer (score 10):

`sample` takes an argument:

```
[*(1..10)].sample(5) #=>[3, 4, 1, 8, 9]
```

No element will be selected twice.

Comment: Not my question, but this is something I didn't know, and can foresee being useful in the future. +1

Answer (score 1):

If the array elements are really very large, you can try to simply shuffle a list of indices and iterate over that:

```
a = %w{a b c d e f g h}

[*0...a.size].shuffle.each do |index|
  puts a[index]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to track those elements you have already selected; what are you going to do, put them in an array of their own?

Shuffle and iterate.  This does not take more memory than tracking those elements already selected.